# Ограничение на количество итераций

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = file[i]; i++)
```

этот код отвечает за вывод количества файлов, сейчас он без ограничений может выводить хоть 100 или 200 файлов, но что нужно в нем изменить что бы он выводил не более 10 файлов?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0, f; i < 10 && f = file[i]; i++)
```

А еще лучше - сделать по человечески

```
var cnt = Math.min(10, file.length);
for (var i = 0, i < cnt; i++) {
  var f = file[i];
  .......
}
```

Comment: `min` может таки? :)

Comment: @teran таки да.

Comment: Пробовал тот и тот код но почемуто вообще ничего не выводет

Comment: @AsXK А что должно выводить? Что такое у Вас `file`? Это массив или какой-то объект? Как Вы его получаете?